# How to set Classpath on Jboss EAP openshift image

Tags: docker, jboss, openshift, wildfly

Image used : https://access.redhat.com/containers/#/registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap70-openshift

I can set an ENV variable but it does not work.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap70-openshift
ENV CLASSPATH $CLASSPATH:/opt/eap/standalone/lib/required_libs/fscontext.jar
```

It sets this variable but I still get following exception,

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory from [Module "org.jboss.as.naming:main" from local module loader @b97c004 (finder: local module finder @4590c9c3 (roots: /opt/eap/modules,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/openshift,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.6.CP,/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base,/opt/eap/modules/system/add-ons/keycloak))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:113)
```

Setting classpath inside container also does not work.

Looking for setting a classpath which would show up in java process like below :

```
[root@9a290d7939bb ~]# ps -ef | grep java
root         1     0  0 Jul18 ?        00:05:49 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java -Dnop -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.library.path=/opt/webserver/lib -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/opt/jolokia/etc/jolokia.properties -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/webserver/endorsed **-classpath /opt/webserver/fscontext.jar:/opt/webserver/ldap.jar** -Dcatalina.base=/opt/webserver -Dcatalina.home=/opt/webserver -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/webserver/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put your lib in /opt/eap/modules or in one of the directory mentionned in the stacktrace ?

Don't forget to create also a module.xml file in EAP_HOME/modules/your/package/name/main, ex :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="your.package.name">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="fscontext.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="com.ibm.mq"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```